# How do I generate a unique ID without using AUTOINCREMENT

Tags: sql, unique

I am exporting data from csv into mysql database, I want the database to generate a unique id for each imported record. I want to use the unique field in generating a receipt number in crystal report.

What would you suggest as the best way of doing this?

Comment: Why avoid autoincrement?  You should be able to give it a suitably large seed value using the AUTO_INCREMENT table option if you want to avoid low numbers.

Comment: You should explain why AUTOINCREMENT is no good to you to get a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to auto increment the only other way to virtually guarantee uniqueness is to use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) as the id.

I say "virtually" as there is a theoretical possibility that the same GUID could be generated twice, but it's effectively zero for all everyday uses. From the Wikipedia article:

> The total number of unique keys (21<sup>28</sup> or 3.4×10<sup>38</sup>) is so large that the probability of the same number being generated twice is extremely small, and certain techniques have been developed to help ensure that numbers are not duplicated.

Comment: Thanks, i would go with the auto_increment function. But i need to know if it would  automatically generated IDs if i use the LOAD DATA INFILE command.  

Also i need to know how to fix the number of digits that appears. i want to convert the numbers to HEX using the hex(id) function, but i want the hex value show in a block of 6. ABCDEF.

Answer (score 2):

Autoincrement is absolutely the right way to do this in MySQL, is there are good reason not to use it?

If you want something more like Oracle's sequences, you can [use another table with an autoincrement column](http://www.geekinterview.com/talk/5271-how-to-create-sequence-in-mysql.html#post19356).